# Question about interpretation of algebraic notation in differential geometry paper

Tags: riemannian-geometry, notation

I am unable to understand the notation of equations (1.1) and (1.6) in page 2 of Kowalski and Belger's paper "[Riemannian metric with the prescribed curvature tensor and all its covariant derivatives at one point](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19941680113)" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1282640)). My intuition is that (1.6) should be iterated derivatives of the special case when $k=0$ but I still couldn't figure out what the notation of the author is supposed to mean. I would be grateful if someone can help.

[image: (1.1) and (1.6) in Kowalski's paper]

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written, you're obviously familiar with the idea that a linear map $a:V\to V$ has a natural action $\mu\mapsto a\cdot \mu$ on the algebra of covariant tensors given by

$$
(a\cdot \mu)(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k \mu(v_1,\dots,v_{i-1},av_i,v_{i+1}\dots, v_k)
$$

My hunch is that notation (1.1) is designed to provide a compact way of writing `partial actions' of endomorphisms on tensors, so that rather than summing over all slots, we just sum a few. In particular, I think

$$
R^{(k-i)}_{Z_k\dots Z_{i+1}}(R_{AB}^{(0)}\cdot R^{(i)})_{Z_i\dots Z_1}(X,Y,U,V)
$$

probably means:

$$
\begin{array}{llll}
R^{(k)}(R_{AB}^{(0)}X,Y,U,V,Z_1,\dots, Z_k) + \\ 
R^{(k)}(X,R_{AB}^{(0)}Y,U,V,Z_1,\dots, Z_k) + \\
R^{(k)}(X,Y,R_{AB}^{(0)}U,V,Z_1,\dots, Z_k) + \\
R^{(k)}(X,Y,U,R_{AB}^{(0)}V,Z_1,\dots, Z_k) + \\\sum_{j=1}^i R^{(k)}(X,Y,U,V,Z_1,\dots,Z_{j-1},R_{AB}^{(0)}Z_j,Z_{j+1},\dots,Z_i,Z_{i+1},\dots,Z_k)
\end{array}
$$

which is like $R_{AB}^{(0)}\cdot R^{(k)}$ but the with terms involving $(R_{AB}^{0}Z_j)_{j=i+1}^k$ omitted. One way to determine whether my hunch is correct is to check whether this last expression equals the left hand side of (1.6) when $R^{(k)} = \nabla^k R$ for a genuine curvature tensor $R$ (I unfortunately don't know enough about identities involving curvature tensors to be able to do this quickly).